# JQuery: insertBefore the entire object

Tags: jquery

Below is the code to select a particular object and insert before all the objects in the list of employee directory items in sharepoint 2010.

If the job title is in the list of `managerTitles`, make this person the first in the list if they're not aready first

```
if($.inArray(jobTitle3, managerTitles) >= 0) {
    // If they're not first in the list, move them there"
    if(personIndex > 0) {
        // Move the manager to first
        $(this).insertBefore($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
    }

    // Insert a block div to create a line break after the manager
    $("<div style='display:block;clear:both;'></div>").insertAfter($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
     //removed this line due to need for multiple heads of a dept -- return false;//Leave the .each iterator
}
```

The code

```
$(this).insertBefore($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
```

doesn't do anything and so as the code

```
$("<div style='display:block;clear:both;'></div>").insertAfter($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
```

but when i try writing something as

```
$("<p>testing</p>").insertBefore($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
```

it works

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Please provide more context. What is `this`?

Comment: Need to show more context before `if` to see what `this` is.

Comment: `this` most likely is not an HTML element which is why it doesn't do anything. And are you sure that `div` is not being added? it's just a blank `div` nothing will show up, but it could still be there

Comment: Also show html structure...might be able to use `prepend()` which will insert at beginning of a container

Comment: this represents the current object

Comment: I have a list of <xsl:attribute name="class">psrch-FullResult</xsl:attribute>

and in the class there is a specific field as jobTitle3. When that matches an array of items, then I should move the entire class result above all the available items in the list.

In the code $(this) represents the current object context.

But the entire class of items is not moved 

with the code  $(this).insertBefore($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));

Comment: Is there a way I can rearrange the list of employees shown in the employee directory page based on certain field values of each employee.Currently, am using javascript/jquery to rearrange using insertBefore and insertAfter, but am not able to fetch the entire div tag to place before another div tag. Any suggestions would be helpful.

$(this) represents the current object. But I don't see any change in the result being displayed. Any suggestions.When a condition is satisfied, I want to move the entire div before all of them and show it on the top and seperate this from the other with a div tag.

Comment: update the question ....big long comments, especially ones with code are very hard to read. You say `$(this)` is current object but show that in the code as requested...it is not unusual for `this` to be misinterpreted